# create column based on column values - loop over column

Tags: pandas, loops, calculated-columns

I would like to create a new column "Group". The integer values from column "Step_ID" should be converted in loop from 1 to 4. See the image below.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd  
data = {'Step_ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
df['Group'] = (df.Step_ID % 4).replace(0 ,4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Step_ID  Group
0         1      1
1         1      1
2         2      2
3         2      2
4         3      3
5         4      4
6         5      1
7         6      2
8         6      2
9         7      3
10        8      4
11        8      4
12        9      1
13       10      2
14       11      3
15       11      3
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the OP would want to handle an edge case. If the values of Step_ID skips over a number (i.e. [1, 2, 4]) this solution would treat that the same as [1, 2, 3]

Comment: @Parsyk Np.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd  

data = {'Step_ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Need to subtract/add 1 so that you get 1-4 instead of 0-3
df1['group'] = ((df1['Step_ID'] - 1) % 4) + 1

df1
```

|  | Step_ID | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 6 | 2 |
| 8 | 6 | 2 |
| 9 | 7 | 3 |
| 10 | 8 | 4 |
| 11 | 8 | 4 |
| 12 | 9 | 1 |
| 13 | 10 | 2 |
| 14 | 11 | 3 |
| 15 | 11 | 3 |

Comment: thank you for the message. But it does not calculate as required. Compare the table with your results with mine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried checking back on the table, and I can't spot the value that was missed. Can you clue me in?